# How to use a cell value as reference in a formula

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have been trying to get a cell reference as text to be used as reference to another sheet:

Got a dropdown menu cell (A2) returning a text string (e.g.: Sheet2, Sheet3) Now I wanted to reference that value in a formula: =$'Sheet2'.D20 (where Sheet2 should be equal to A2)

I tried from going =$A2.D20 to =INDIRECT("A2").D20 and many more variations, only getting more errors.. Is there someone out there that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try `INDIRECT("$'"&A2&"'.D20")`

Comment: Worked like a charm... thanks, finally can give this rest after hours of trying around!

Answer (score 1):

Máté Juhász wrote in the comment:

> Try `INDIRECT("$'"&A2&"'.D20")`

*This was reproduced as an answer so that it can be closed properly.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question.*